# how to create an numerical/index scrollbar in android

Tags: android

My purpose is to obtain something like this:

[image]

I want to be able to create a similar side menu where you can slide on specific numbers given. Then the content shown will be changed depending on what number is selected.

Does anyone know a good approach to deal with this and create a good side menu

Answer (score 0):

Try my sample layout for scroll

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
   android:fadeScrollbars="true"
   android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
   <LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/tt"  >
   <TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Text one.."
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:background="#ffffff"
   android:textSize="20dip"/>
   <HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
   android:fadeScrollbars="true"
   android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"   >
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/abc"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     <ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/fgj"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/ggcgh"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/thhh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/fhg"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />
  <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/jgeraej"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
  <ImageView
  android:src="@drawable/jhdfdjh"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"/>
  </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:text="Text two.."
  android:textSize="20dip"/>
 <HorizontalScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
   android:fadeScrollbars="true"
 android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
  android:src="@drawable/thhh"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"/>
  <ImageView
  android:src="@drawable/abc"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 <ImageView
  android:src="@drawable/fgj"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
   <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/hghhgh"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />
   <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/jgeraej"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
   <ImageView
   android:src="@drawable/fhg"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/thhh"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
     </LinearLayout>
     </HorizontalScrollView>
     </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
```

[See this Example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example)